# Null reference exception getting from method

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ado.net

I'm using SQLHELPER classes for getting the id from the procedure.
I had written the following code :

```
string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
public int CheckUser(string userName,string password)
    {
        SqlParameter[] spc = new SqlParameter[5];
        spc = SqlHelperParameterCache.GetSpParameterSet(constr, "CheckUser");
        spc[0].Value = userName;
        spc[1].Value =password;
        spc[2] = new SqlParameter("@userExist", SqlDbType.Int, 32);
        spc[2].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        int res = (int)SqlHelper.ExecuteScalar(constr, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "CheckUser", spc);

        return res;
    }
```

I'm pssing the username and password but I'm facing "Null reference exception was unhandled by the user" run time exception. When I debug I got the both values which I sent exactly.

```
Create proc CheckUser
@userName varchar(50),
@password varchar(50),
@userExist int output
as
  begin
   set @userExist= (select COUNT(*) 
                from tbluserInfo 
                where  UserName=@userName and [Password]=@password)

    select [uid] from tbluserInfo 
            where  UserName=@userName and [Password]=@password

 end
```

[Null Ref QuickWatch. Click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVwOE.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: you have take `SqlParameter[5]` so length is 5 and pass only 3 parameters is there any reason behind this?

Comment: Can you share you Procedure named "CheckUser"? code

Comment: @Curiousdev ,Thanks for that. I replaced it to 3, but still the exception is raising.

Comment: ohh ohkk one more thing can you please check is `SqlHelper.ExecuteScalar(constr, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "CheckUser", spc)` this giving a value or null ? it may be cause the issue

Comment: @MuradGaribzada , Now you can find procedure too.

Comment: @Curiousdev , It's return type is object itself.  giving means you mean any other than return type ?

Comment: set @userExist= (select isnull(COUNT(*),0)
                from tbluserInfo 
                where  UserName=@userName and [Password]=@password)  check this please

Comment: okay. I'll try.

Comment: Here I'm not getting any SQLException.

Comment: If @userExist is null then (int)SqlHelper.ExecuteScalar(constr, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "CheckUser", spc); this line will return Null reference exception

Comment: Might be, It's an output parameter. How can I handle it then ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to return `@userExist` which you have set from SP please find below updated SP

**UPDATED**

```
Create proc CheckUser
@userName varchar(50),
@password varchar(50),
@userExist int output
as
  begin
   set @userExist= (select isnull([uid],0) from tbluserInfo 
            where  UserName=@userName and [Password]=@password)

   return @userExist;

 end
```

Comment: returned the output parameter, still facing the same issue. I'm getting null reference exception not sqlexception. Please think in that way also.

Comment: PLease put a debug point and than quick watch on `SqlHelper.ExecuteScalar(constr, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "CheckUser", spc)` this line what you'r getting check if debug reached at this line or not if not which line you'r getting exception

Comment: I'm getting Null in quickwatch.  Please check the image I had attached below the Quest.

Comment: Ohh that's weird can you show the `SqlHelper.ExecuteScalar` method?